# What is OracleXETNSListener service?

Tags: windows, oracle-11g

What OracleXETNSListener service does?

I know it is installed with Oracle (11g Express), but I couldn't find a description.

What I checked:

- The service description field is empty.
- Google hits show only problems with the service, not it's purpose
- No relevant hit on speruser, dba.stackexchange, stackowerflow

Comment: I did not find oracle-11g tag, only oracle-10g.

Comment: TNS stands for [Transparent Network Substrate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparent_Network_Substrate).

Comment: It’s basically the main listener for your database instances.

Comment: remote clients connect to this service/port, in order to connect to and query your databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service is a [TNS service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparent_Network_Substrate) for your Oracle XE instance. Oracle uses TNS as a method of connecting with the Oracle database instance